# Custom Navigation Title - SWIFT

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, uinavigationitem

I would like to customize my navigation title but run into a problem. "String is not identical to NSObject". Can someone point me in the right direction? My code is below,

```
let font = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue", size: 15.0)
let textFont = [NSFontAttributeName: font]
let navText = [NSAttributedString(string: "MY STRING HERE", attributes: textFont)]

var navString = UILabel()
navString.appendAttributedString(navText)
self.navigationItem.titleView = navString
```

UPDATE: I was able to solve the problem with the following code,

```
    var navString: NSString = "MY STRING HERE"
    var completedNavString = NSMutableAttributedString()

    completedNavString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: navString as String, attributes: [NSFontAttributeName:UIFont(name: "Georgia", size: 18.0)!])

    var navLabel = UILabel()
    navLabel.attributedText = completedNavString
    navLabel.sizeToFit()
    self.navigationItem.titleView = navLabel
```

Comment: Please include the full error trace in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
var navString = UILabel()
navString.appendAttributedString(navText)
```

You can't "append" anything to a UILabel. Try `navString.attributedText = navText`.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. Im still getting the error message for "let navText = [NSAttributedString(string: "MY STRING HERE", attributes: textFont)]"

Comment: Remove the square brackets. This is Swift, not Objective-C!